# How can I show all YouTube videos with their descriptions expanded by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, stylesheet

I think the curator script dictates the CSS size but I can't get it just right.

Here in this jsfiddle you'll see:
https://jsfiddle.net/supplement/fmjrvsze/1/

It may be easier to look at it directly on the website:
https://www.mailmyprescriptions.com

Where it displays the content the top two YouTube videos have the `Read more` buttons and the bottom two are fully expanded.

I want all four (all even when you use the `Next` buttons) on the page to be fully expanded and not have the `Read more` button at all.

I've tried adjusting the `padding-top` from `4em` to `0em` and I got it almost correct but there was still a bit of transparent haze.

```
.crt-post-v2.crt-post-max-height .crt-post-max-height-read-more {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 4em;
    margin: 0em;
    background: transparent;
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, transparent), color-stop(50%, #efefef));
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #efefef 50%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0);
}
```

Don't do much front end or mobile development anymore so any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Help please.

I want them to all look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bharata Please find code in code pen now and thank you for your help.  https://codepen.io/radzikowski/pen/JevGNd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an inline `max-height:316px` style, which is causing this.

Here is the complete solution. check out the below codepen.

https://codepen.io/onejeet/pen/NEMxVe

```
$('.crt-post-c').css('max-height','500px');

$('.crt-post-read-more-button').css('display','none');
$('.crt-post-max-height-read-more').css('background','none');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all you have to do is remove that display:block; and then set a new max-height to whatever is appropriate. 600px or something

Comment: That seemed to work for individual youtube box but not all of them. I need them all to be fully expanded.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the following values in CSS: `max-height` and `min-height` values on all elements with class `.crt-post-c` and `display` values on all elements with class `.crt-post-max-height-read-more` like follows:

```
var crtPosts = document.querySelectorAll('.crt-post-c'),
    crtPostsReadMore = document.querySelectorAll('.crt-post-max-height-read-more');

for(var i = crtPosts.length; i--;)
{
    crtPosts[i].style.maxHeight = '800px';
    crtPosts[i].style.minHeight = '400px';
}
for(var i = crtPostsReadMore.length; i--;)
    crtPostsReadMore[i].style.display = 'none';
```

Here is the **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVxaay)**.
I hope this is what you want.